# Is there a spreadsheet API facade for Java?

Tags: library, java, spreadsheet

There are multiple Java libraries for different kinds of spreadsheets, e.g. [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) for Microsoft Excel files, [jOpenDocument](https://www.jopendocument.org/) for ODS (OpenDocument Spreadsheets) files and [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/libraries) for Google Sheets. Is there a library that abstracts from specific formats/vendors and offers a uniform interface to spreadsheets of different vendors? A facade similar to what S[imple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J)](https://www.slf4j.org/) is for logging?

To my surprise I couldn't find an established open source library via a web search, and ChatGPT only hallucinated such libraries. The only candidate library I found is [spreadsheet4j](https://github.com/nbbrd/spreadsheet4j), but it does not seem to support Google Sheets, is poorly documented and has only one contributor and one star on GitHub, which does not make me very confident in using it.

I am aware that such a library very likely cannot cover all features of all formats/vendors, so I am only looking for a facade that covers the common subset of features.

I am also aware that there may be workarounds involving conversion of formats. But if I downloaded a Google spreadsheet as Excel/ODS file and then made local changes, I could probably not upload them with overwriting the spreadsheet's history.